# Multi Layer Neural Network TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to train the train a 4 layer neural network in tensor flow for recognizing alphabets. But my accuracy comes out to be around 10% while my accuracy on the same dataset with 3 layers was 90%. The loss is also **nan** for some iterations. I can't seem to find the problem. Below is the code for generating the computation graph.

```
batch_size = 128

beta = 0.01
inputs = image_size*image_size
hidden_neurons = [inputs, 1024, 512, 256,]
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
  global_step = tf.Variable(0) 
  # Input data. For the training data, we use a placeholder that will be fed
  # at run time with a training minibatch.
  tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                    shape=(batch_size, image_size * image_size))
  tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
  tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
  tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

  #Hidden Layer Neurons
  tf_hidden_neurons_1 = tf.constant(1024)
  tf_hidden_neurons_2 = tf.constant(512)

  weights_1 = tf.Variable(
  tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size, tf_hidden_neurons_1]))
  biases_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([tf_hidden_neurons_1]))
  weights_2 = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([tf_hidden_neurons_1, tf_hidden_neurons_2]))
  biases_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([tf_hidden_neurons_2]))
  weights_3 = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([tf_hidden_neurons_2, num_labels]))
  biases_3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))


  # Training computation.
  reluActivations_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights_1) + biases_1)
  reluActivations_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reluActivations_1, weights_2) + biases_2)
  logits = tf.matmul(reluActivations_2, weights_3) + biases_3
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(
  tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf_train_labels, logits=logits))

  # Add Regularization
  regulizationTerm = tf.nn.l2_loss(weights_1) + tf.nn.l2_loss(weights_2) +tf.nn.l2_loss(weights_3)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss + beta*regulizationTerm)

  # Optimizer.
  learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.3, global_step, 100000, 0.7, staircase=True)
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
#   optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

  # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
  train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
  valid_prediction = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights_1) + biases_1)
  valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(valid_prediction, weights_2) + biases_2)
  test_prediction = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights_1) + biases_1)
  test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(test_prediction, weights_2) + biases_2)
```

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're familiar about vanishing gradient and exploding gradients problem.

In most cases you get nan when gradients are too less or they're exploding. Use `np.clip` for clipping gradient that way you should not get any nan. After you solve this problem we can move ahead with low accuracy problem of yours.